# Why does sed report "Invalid command code" for tilde?

Tags: unix, sed

I am running the following sed command. I want to extract every 4th line starting at the second line:

```
input:
$ sed -n '2~4p' filename

output:
sed: 1: "2~4p": invalid command code ~
```

Does anyone know why this is occurring? I am using mac OSX 10.8.

I know the following awk command command will do: $ awk "NR%4==2  {print}"

I'm curious why tilde is invalid for this sed command.

Comment: MacOSX does not run the gnu sed that supports ~.

Comment: You can install GNU sed on a Mac fairly simply by compiling from source - without Homebrew or MacPorts.

Comment: You can shorten the `awk` to: `awk 'NR%4==2' file`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess you're in Mac OS X. It has the BSD implementation of `sed` and if you search for `~` in the `man` page you'll find nothing, because it's not there.

You can install the GNU implementation, for example with MacPorts:

```
sudo port install gsed
```

or Brew:

```
brew install gnu-sed
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 sed -n '1d;N;N;N;P;d' YourFile
```

one liner

- passe 1 line (delete also mean go to end of script directly)
- load 3 line more than the current
- print the 1st line
- delete the loaded line
- restart action

Comment: this command does not work for me on macOS.